# Real-time color change in terminal (before user sends the command)

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, bashrc, rxvt

I could not find a better way to write the title, so sorry if it is not as specific as it should.

For my case, I would like to make the **first word** (that we know it will be separated of the rest of the command by **a space character**) in my terminal to be colored, for example, yellow. It's similar to what the terminal in Visual Studio Code does, where the command it's actually yellow for the first word.

I know I can edit the `PS1` variable in `.bashrc`, to end with the yellow xterm color escape sequence, but that would mean it will also color the rest.

I would like to know, if there is a way of using regex, working programatically or whatever (hopefully without installing any extra package or terminal) to read in "real-time" what the user is writing and as soon as a space character is used, then change the color to "normal".

If it's ever needed, I'm using Manjaro with i3 and my terminal is urxvt. Thanks for any help, and sorry for my English, I'm not native.

Comment: (1) I doubt that this is possible.  (2) The first word of a command is not necessarily terminated by a space; consider `date>date.out` and `ls&&rm *`.

Comment: Thank you @Scott ! I thought so too.